# Xcode unable to archive react native project

Tags: ios, react-native

I am getting this error when I try to archive my React Native project.

I am able to run debug/release on iPhone and Simulator. `react-native run` works as well.

I have read through similar issues and tried:

1. Make sure I'm opening `xcworkspace` instead of `xcodeproj`.
2. Deleting `Podfile.lock` and running `pod install` and cleaning project.
3. Setting *Build Active Architecture Only* to *Yes*

Build output:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/teacher-gkqevnksdssljsbrniwvxaoxiwhi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/teacher/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/DoubleConversion'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/teacher-gkqevnksdssljsbrniwvxaoxiwhi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/teacher/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Folly'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/teacher-gkqevnksdssljsbrniwvxaoxiwhi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/teacher/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/teacher-gkqevnksdssljsbrniwvxaoxiwhi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/teacher/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/teacher-gkqevnksdssljsbrniwvxaoxiwhi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/teacher/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/glog'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/teacher-gkqevnksdssljsbrniwvxaoxiwhi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/teacher/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/react-native-google-maps'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/teacher-gkqevnksdssljsbrniwvxaoxiwhi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/teacher/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/react-native-maps'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/teacher-gkqevnksdssljsbrniwvxaoxiwhi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/teacher/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/react-native-video'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/teacher-gkqevnksdssljsbrniwvxaoxiwhi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/teacher/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/yoga'
ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try turning it off and on again? Try rebooting your Mac, often these problems go away.

Also try deleting the whole contents of DerivedData, in your case:

```
rm -rf /Users/mans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

Does it work with some fresh project you get somewhere from GitHub?